# Amazon S3 listing "directories"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've created a hierarchy in S3 via the AWS S3 Management Console. If I run the following code to list the bucket:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(CRED);
ListObjectsRequest lor = new ListObjectsRequest()
                             .withBucketName("myBucket")
                             .withPrefix("code/");
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(lor);
for (S3ObjectSummary summary: objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
    System.out.println(summary.getKey());
}
```

I get:

```
code/ 
code/03000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000/ 
code/03000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000/special.js 
code/03000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000/test.js 
code/03000000-0002-0000-0000-000000000000/
```

Which is exactly what I would expect. If I add a delimiter though, so that I only list the content directly under "code/" I now don't get any sub "directories" back.

Change line above (add withDelimiter() on the end) to:

```
ListObjectsRequest lor = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("myBucket")
                                                 .withPrefix("code/")
                                                 .withDelimiter("/");
```

And I now only get:

```
code/
```

I know that S3 doesn't have "directories", instead delimited keys, but this behaviour seems odd? How would I list what is only immediately below "code"?

Comment: have you tried `withPrefix("code")` (omitting the slash)

Comment: Yep, that gets me nothing. Per the AWS doco you need to append the trailing delimiter to the prefix.

Comment: This answer is more complete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653694/listing-just-the-sub-folders-in-an-s3-bucket

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Where you have keys that have no content S3 considers them "Common Prefixes":

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html#getCommonPrefixes%28%29

> public List getCommonPrefixes()
>
> Gets the common prefixes included in this object listing. Common
>   prefixes are only present if a delimiter was specified in the original
>   request.
>
> Each common prefix represents a set of keys in the S3 bucket that have
>   been condensed and omitted from the object summary results. This
>   allows applications to organize and browse their keys hierarchically,
>   similar to how a file system organizes files into directories.
>
> For example, consider a bucket that contains the following keys:
>
> "foo/bar/baz"
>   "foo/bar/bash"
>   "foo/bar/bang"
>   "foo/boo"
>
> If calling listObjects with the prefix="foo/" and the delimiter="/" on
>   this bucket, the returned S3ObjectListing will contain one entry in
>   the common prefixes list ("foo/bar/") and none of the keys beginning
>   with that common prefix will be included in the object summaries list.
>
> Returns: The list of common prefixes included in this object listing,
>   which might be an empty list if no common prefixes were found.

Comment: It returns foo/, foo/boo, and has foo/bar in common prefixes. Is that correct?

Comment: There is an example is this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653694/listing-just-the-sub-folders-in-an-s3-bucket

Comment: Also a code sample can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520124/5071635

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
This below code worked for me to list all directories in s3.

private static String bucket_name = "";
private static String secret_key = "";
private static String access_key = "";
private static String Regions region = Regions.SELECT_REGION;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(listKeysInBucket(bucket_name, "/"));
    }

    public static List<String> listKeysInBucket(String bucketName, String prefix) {
        boolean isTopLevel = false;
        String delimiter = "/";
        if (prefix.equals("") || prefix.equals(delimiter)) {
            isTopLevel = true;
        }
        if (!prefix.endsWith(delimiter)) {
            prefix += delimiter;
        }

        ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = null;
        if (isTopLevel) {
            listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName).withDelimiter(delimiter);
        } else {
            listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(prefix)
                    .withDelimiter(delimiter);
        }

        ObjectListing objects = s3Client().listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        return objects.getCommonPrefixes();
    }

    public static AmazonS3 s3Client() {
        AWSCredentials s3Configs = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key,secret_key);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(s3Configs)).withRegion(region )
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify any directory hierarchy that lists buckets. When prefix is ​​set to "" or "/", it indicates the first-level directory of the bucket. When setting a specific subdirectory, the list of keys of the subdirectory is displayed.

Reference to [Charles Menguy's answer in 'Amazon S3 listing “directories”'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653973/7739839), and added some modifications.

```
  public List<String> listKeysInBucket(String bucketName, String prefix) {
    Boolean isTopLevel = false;
    String delimiter = "/";
    if(prefix == "" || prefix == "/") {
      isTopLevel = true;
    }
    if (!prefix.endsWith(delimiter)) {
      prefix += delimiter;
    }

    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = null;
    if (isTopLevel) {
      listObjectsRequest =
          new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName).withDelimiter(delimiter);
    } else {
      listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(prefix)
          .withDelimiter(delimiter);
    }
    ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
    return objects.getCommonPrefixes();
  }
```