# Listing files in a specific "folder" of a AWS S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to list all files contained in a certain folder contained in my S3 bucket.

The folder structure is the following

```
/my-bucket/users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>
```

I have files related to users and files related to a certain user's contact.
I need to list both.

To list files I'm using this code:

```
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("my-bucket")
                .withPrefix("some-prefix").withDelimiter("/");
ObjectListing objects = transferManager.getAmazonS3Client().listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
```

To list a certain user's files I'm using this prefix:

`users/<user-id>/`

and I'm correctly getting all files in the directory excluding `contacts` subdirectory, for example:

```
users/<user-id>/file1.txt
users/<user-id>/file2.txt
users/<user-id>/file3.txt
```

To list a certain user contact's files instead I'm using this prefix:

`users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>/`

but in this case I'm getting also the 
directory itself as a returned object:

```
users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>/file1.txt
users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>/file2.txt
users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>/
```

Why am I getting this behaviour? What's different beetween the two listing requests? I need to list only files in the directory, excluding sub-directories.

Comment: This behavior would be expected if you actually created the "empty folder" in the console, because that action actually creates an empty object with the key `path/to/my/folder/` so the console has a placeholder.  Did you do that, while testing?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I didn't create any empty folder. Infact all files are uploaded by the application using the folder structure I reported as prefix for the file key.

Comment: You might want to try a `GET` on the apparent object with trailing slash, then, because if you didn't create a folder and you did use the `/` delimiter `withDelimiter("/")` when listing the objects, this should mean that you do in fact have an object named with a trailing slash, possibly due to a bug in your code that created one that way.  Such an object would likely be invisible in the console.

Comment: Here is the code: http://codeflex.co/get-list-of-objects-from-s3-directory/

Comment: Indeed Michael is right, there is an object with that key in your bucket.  Run this command to remove it `aws s3api delete-object --bucket X --key path/to/my/folder/`.  And make sure your code doesn't create that object again.

Comment: One can check this if they are not able to list objects/files in specific folder https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481553/8874958

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Everything in S3 is an object. To you, it may be files and folders. But to S3, they're just objects.

Objects that end with the delimiter (`/` in most cases) are usually perceived as a folder, but it's not always the case. It depends on the application. Again, in your case, you're interpretting it as a folder. S3 is not. It's just another object.

In your case above, the object `users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>/` exists in S3 as a distinct object, but the object `users/<user-id>/` does not. That's the difference in your responses. Why they're like that, we cannot tell you, but someone made the object in one case, and didn't in the other. You don't see it in the AWS Management Console because the console is interpreting it as a folder and hiding it from you.

Since S3 just sees these things as objects, it won't "exclude" certain things for you. It's up to the client to deal with the objects as they should be dealt with.

**Your Solution**

Since you're the one that doesn't want the folder objects, you can exclude it yourself by checking the last character for a `/`. If it is, then ignore the object from the response.

Comment: May I get same list with http Post Request?

Answer (score 77):

While everybody say that there are no directories and files in s3, but only objects (and buckets), which is absolutely true, I would suggest to take advantage of CommonPrefixes, described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561432/amazon-s3-listing-directories) answer.
So, you can do following to get list of "folders" (commonPrefixes) and "files" (objectSummaries):

```
ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucket.getName()).withPrefix(prefix).withDelimiter(DELIMITER);
ListObjectsV2Result listing = s3Client.listObjectsV2(req);
for (String commonPrefix : listing.getCommonPrefixes()) {
        System.out.println(commonPrefix);
}
for (S3ObjectSummary summary: listing.getObjectSummaries()) {
    System.out.println(summary.getKey());
}
```

In your case, for objectSummaries (files) it should return (in case of correct prefix): 
*users/user-id/contacts/contact-id/file1.txt*
*users/user-id/contacts/contact-id/file2.txt*
for commonPrefixes:
*users/user-id/contacts/contact-id/*

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

Comment: ListObjectsV2 is still not used prominently. .getCommonPrefixes() is really the way to go here..

Comment: Check this article here, seems like it's exactly what are you looking: http://codeflex.co/get-list-of-objects-from-s3-directory/

Comment: This shoud be the best answer

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is only to take the files and not the folder, the approach I made was to use the file `size` as a filter. This property is the current size of the file hosted by AWS. All the folders return 0 in that property.
The following is a C# code using linq but it shouldn't be hard to translate to Java.

```
var amazonClient = new AmazonS3Client(key, secretKey, region);
var listObjectsRequest= new ListObjectsRequest
            {
                BucketName = 'someBucketName',
                Delimiter = 'someDelimiter',
                Prefix = 'somePrefix'
            };
var objects = amazonClient.ListObjects(listObjectsRequest);
var objectsInFolder = objects.S3Objects.Where(file => file.Size > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: A reasonable answer although the purist in me says a file is a file even if it is zero bytes. File names can't end with a '/' and file names cannot be zero length - I think they are better decision makers than size

Answer (score 3):

you can check the type. s3 has a special *application/x-directory*

```
bucket.objects({:delimiter=>"/", :prefix=>"f1/"}).each { |obj| p obj.object.content_type }
```

Answer (score 1):

As other have already said, everything in S3 is an object. To you, it may be files and folders. But to S3, they're just objects.

If you don't need objects which end with a '/' you can safely delete them e.g. via REST api or AWS Java SDK (I assume you have write access). You will not lose "nested files" (there no files, so you will not lose objects whose names are prefixed with the key you delete)

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()).withRegion("region").build();
amazonS3.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest("my-bucket", "users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>/"));
```

Please note that I'm using `ProfileCredentialsProvider` so that my requests are not anonymous. Otherwise, you will not be able to delete an object. I have my AWS keep key stored in ~/.aws/credentials file.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS SDK for Java 2.x You can use this code:

```java
ListObjectsV2Request req = ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
        .bucket("bucketName")
        .prefix(prefix)
        .delimiter("/")
        .build();

ListObjectsV2Response listing = s3Client.listObjectsV2(req);

for (S3Object object: listing.contents()) {
    System.out.println(object.key());
}
```

And if your prefix is some things like this `Images/602cef3dd96bda7c2e97b8ad/` output will be:

```
Images/602cef3dd96bda7c2e97b8ad/
Images/602cef3dd96bda7c2e97b8ad/06136e02_20220501.jpg
Images/602cef3dd96bda7c2e97b8ad/0638da47_20220501.jpg
Images/602cef3dd96bda7c2e97b8ad/142e98f1_20220501.jpg
Images/602cef3dd96bda7c2e97b8ad/160ca9f1_20220501.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

S3 does not have directories, while you can list files in a pseudo directory manner like you demonstrated, there is no directory "file" per-se.
You may of inadvertently created a data file called `users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>/`.

Comment: I can't see any `users/<user-id>/contacts/<contact-id>/` file in my management console. but, if it exists, how can I exclude this?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe helpful for Rust `aws-sdk-s3` users:

```
  let mut output = s3_client.list_objects_v2()
    .bucket("bucketname")
    //limit listing to bucketname/The/Parent/Object/Name
    .prefix("The/Parent/Object/Name/") 
    .send().await?;
  
  loop{
    if let Some(objects) = output.contents() {
      for object in objects {
        println!("Object: {:}", object.key().unwrap())
      }
    }
  
    if output.is_truncated() {
      output = s3_client.list_objects_v2()
               .bucket("bucketname")
               //limit listing to bucketname/The/Parent/Object/Name
               .prefix("The/Parent/Object/Name/") 
               .continuation_token(output.next_continuation_token().unwrap())
               .send().await?
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Voting down without giving feedback about what exactly u didn't like. Is that fair?

Answer (score -3):

Based on @davioooh answer.
This code is worked for me.

```
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("your-bucket")
            .withPrefix("your/folder/path/").withDelimiter("/");
```