# AWS S3 listFiles - How can i get directory path?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

Is it possible to get all files name from s3 bucket?
In my local spring boot project, i wrote something like, and it works.

```
File[] files = new File("/myfiles").listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            filesDir.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
```

On AWS i try this, but it doesnt work.

```
File[] files = new File("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/myfiles/").listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                filesDir.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
```

What is wrong, how can i get directory path from s3?

Comment: Plz take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051789/listing-files-in-a-specific-folder-of-a-aws-s3-bucket . Hope you will get the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7465152/4067759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to connect to S3. To do this, following below suggest.
Add in your pom the AWS API

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.113</version>
</dependency>
```

You will create an instance of AmazonS3 service. Like this:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("ACCESS KEY", "SECRET KEY");
AmazonS3 service AmazonS3Client.builder()
             .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
             .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration("YOUR_ENDPOINT", "YOUR_REGION"))
             .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
             .build();
```

After connecting, you can retrieve the information about the bucket using the service you just have created.

```
ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("bucket").withPrefix("path_your_file_or_folder");
ListObjectsV2Result result = service.listObjectsV2(req)
for (S3ObjectSummary object: result .getObjectSummaries()){
    String key = object.getKey(); //your object it's here.
}
```

After getting the key to your file, you can download it.
I hope this helps you.