# How to list all files from a specific S3 Bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 bucket for my project where I am uploading images and listing images using APIs, which is working pretty fine.

Now I want to list all files of a specific S3 bucket/folder (listing of objects of the specific bucket).

Here is the screenshot of my S3 bucket:

[image: s3-bucket]

**I tried to give bucket names like**

1. `wevieu/development/user_default/`
2. `wevieu/development/user_default`
3. `s3://wevieu/development/user_default/`

etc. but nothing helped me.

**Most of the time I am getting this error or any other error with 400 response:**

> The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code:
> 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey;

I tried [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8027265/8874958) , [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38051789/8874958) solutions but didn't get help from any of this.

Help me if anyone have done this before successfully.

**Note:** I am using this SDK version *com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.423*

Comment: Do you have actual code to show that you tried? Bucket name is `wevieu`, not the one you tried.

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows that your bucket name is `wevieu`.

Comment: Please Edit your question and show us your code. The bucket name should **ONLY** be `wevieu`, with no directories. If you wish to list a subdirectory, then use `bucket = 'wevieu', prefix = 'development/user_default/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I got the solution.

You need to add the permissions before listing objects in your S3. If permissions are missing then your code will give you errors.

The code that I did use is this, which was not working before adding permission.

After adding permissions, I am able to list all objects.

```
objectListing = s3client.listObjects("wevieu", "development/user_default");
        if (objectListing != null) {
            List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjectSummariesList = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
            if (!s3ObjectSummariesList.isEmpty()) {
                for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : s3ObjectSummariesList) {
                    System.out.println("file name:"+objectSummary.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the latest Amazon S3 V2 API as opposed to the old V1 API. Amazon strongly recommends moving to V2.

**The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.**

Here is the solution using the S3 Java V2 API:

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.list_objects.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.list_objects.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class ListObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    ListObjects <bucketName> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket from which objects are read. \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 1) {
           System.out.println(USAGE);
           System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        listBucketObjects(s3, bucketName);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.list_objects.main]
    public static void listBucketObjects(S3Client s3, String bucketName ) {

       try {
            ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest
                    .builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            ListObjectsResponse res = s3.listObjects(listObjects);
            List<S3Object> objects = res.contents();

            for (ListIterator iterVals = objects.listIterator(); iterVals.hasNext(); ) {
                S3Object myValue = (S3Object) iterVals.next();
                System.out.print("\n The name of the key is " + myValue.key());
                System.out.print("\n The object is " + calKb(myValue.size()) + " KBs");
                System.out.print("\n The owner is " + myValue.owner());

             }

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //convert bytes to kbs
    private static long calKb(Long val) {
        return val/1024;
    }
```

// snippet-end:[s3.java2.list_objects.main]
}

You can find other Amazon S3 code examples here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/s3

Comment: You're right but the project is old and if I update the SDK then I have to update the upload file code along with other S3 related code.

Comment: I wanted to let you know V2 was available. Some DEVs using AWS Java APIs are not aware .