# S3 return less object then maxKeys

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using S3 with java sdk. If I set MaxKeys = 2 that it return only 1 result, but without it 1000. In bucket with this prefix are more than 1000 objects. If I set 5 it return 3 etc. Why it does not return the listSize number of object?

```
final ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
                    .withBucketName(client.getBucketName())
                    .withPrefix(prefix)
                    .withMaxKeys(listSize);

    final ListObjectsV2Result result = client.getAmazonS3Client().listObjectsV2(request);
```

Without max-key it returns 774 only (on this place are more that 1000). Seems that this happened only with on ECS and not with simple S3

Comment: Can you please provide some more details? Sample prefix and say - 10 keys? That is really hard to guess. It can be related to delimiter, or at least that is all what comes to my mind at the moment.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski all keys look like preffix/middle/suffix.jpg    
and delimeter is /.
All have 3 parts and prefix for searching is preffix/middle/

Comment: I did the same, and that works for me... That is why I've asked for real values, or at least something close to them.

Comment: See your point... I'm always using delimiter, and that is different in your code. Also check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561432/amazon-s3-listing-directories -

Comment: @MichałZaborowski what do you mean "I'm always using delimiter"?

Comment: `.withDelimiter("/")` - same as your `withPrefix`, however API is a bit tricky here, so please see linked post. Looks like I was just lucky.