# S3 bucket how to list the object in current folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, list, amazon-s3, filter

In my s3 bucket, my data is listed as following

```
test/
dev/
data1.txt
data2.txt
```

`s3_paths = S3_BUCKET.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix_string)`

I only wanna get the object of

```
data1.txt
data2.txt
```

If there is any way to do it instead of digging into `test/` and `dev/` folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 listing "directories"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561432/amazon-s3-listing-directories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, for this one we only need to add `Delimiter='/'` that's it.

`s3_paths = S3_BUCKET.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix_string, Delimiter='/')`. Now it print out all the

```
prefix_string
data1.txt
data2.txt
```

without digging into `test/` and `dev/` folder.